# Choose a font among all possible and install it

Tags: installation, 13.04, fonts

I do not want to install all the fonts available in the Ubuntu repositories. Instead, I want to look at them and to click one (or more) to be installed.

Some softwares:

- [FontInstall](http://laugier.site90.com/fontInstall) seems to be unmaintained and I did not see the license
- gnome-font-viewer displays only the already installed fonts
- Synaptic:  does not display the fonts, does not indicate the family font and the Category fonts is not always respected.
- fontmatrix does not seems to display fonts from repository

What is your favorite way to handle font selection/installation?
Is there an up-to-date page on the net explaining this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Simple font preview.

> A simple tool to view and compare fonts installed on your system. It
>   has currently following features,
>
> - A list of all fonts available (the left pane)
> - A list of font previews (the right pane)
> - Configurable preview text and font size
> - Configurable foreground and background colors used in the preview    pane

To install [**Simple font preview** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-specimen/)

Another way is to use Gnome font viewer, but you have to have the fonts available locally, and you can view them on at a time.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gnome-font-viewer <path-to-font-file>
```

That will open a window that allows you to view the font, and install it if you like it.

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>

Comment: I am sorry but gnome-specimen (Simple font preview and compare) does not install font from Ubuntu repository. What do you advice me?

Comment: Are there any specific fonts that you're trying to install?  The way I did it, was to download the one that I know I want, view them, and then install.  Also take a look at [Fonts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fonts)

Comment: I am looking for a fantasy font like the one in [this picture](http://www.immeublesenfete.com/fichiers/fckeditor/Image/IEF/media/img/nav/nav_bckg_1.jpg) (the bottom text in orange).

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://www.1001fonts.com/), you maybe able to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look tomorrow morning. I am going to sleep. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Mitch. I finally used the font "[Spicy Rice](http://www.1001fonts.com/spicy-rice-font.html#license)" to render [this poster](http://lmap.org/tst/hessling/cs/notre_fete_des_voisins/notre_fete_des_voisins.jpg). Cheers

Comment: Yep, the previous picture was http://lmap.org/tst/hessling/cs/notre_fete_des_voisins/2007.jpg

Comment: I'm glad it all worked out :)